# Which user has this file open? Automated

Tags: powershell

I have a list of about 1000 PSTs that do not have an active directory owner assigned, nor is the folder, or file name identifiable to a user.

I would like to know what user has this file open so that I can identify the owner.

Given a list of file names.

```
C:\asdf.pst
C:\fdsa.pst
```

And a computer.

Murigar

I believe one could use `OpenFiles.exe` to produce a list of all open files and then extract this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user opens a PST file it creates a temporary file using a filename like ~asdf.pst.tmp. You can check the owner of that file to see who has the PST open.

```
Get-ChildItem "\\server\folder\*.pst.tmp" -Force | ForEach-Object {
    $acl = Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName
    $owner = $acl.Owner
    $file = $_.Name.Replace("~","").Replace(".tmp","")
    "$file is currently open by $owner"
    }
```